# Why can't I compile this command-line OpenCV Mac application?

Tags: xcode, macos, opencv

Following is my step:

1)create a command line tool project "OpenCV"

2)add files to the project which are in /usr/local/lib with suffix 2.4.2, such as 
"libopencv_calib3d.2.4.2.dylib"

3)add "/usr/local/include" to project's Header Search Path

4)type this program:

```
#include <opencv2/opencv.hpp>
#include <opencv2/highgui/highgui.hpp>
#include <opencv/cvaux.hpp>

int main(int argc, char** argv)
{
    IplImage * pInpImg = 0;

    // Load an image from file - change this based on your image name
    pInpImg = cvLoadImage("my_image.jpg", CV_LOAD_IMAGE_UNCHANGED);
    if(!pInpImg)
    {
        fprintf(stderr, "failed to load input image\n");
        return -1;
    }

    // Write the image to a file with a different name,
    // using a different image format -- .png instead of .jpg
    if( !cvSaveImage("my_image_copy.png", pInpImg) )
    {
        fprintf(stderr, "failed to write image file\n");
    }

    // Remember to free image memory after using it!
    cvReleaseImage(&pInpImg);

    return 0;
}
```

However, I get error :

```
ld: library not found for -lopencv_calib3d.2.4.2
clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)
```

Where is the problem?

I'm using mountain lion and Xcode 4.4

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You don't need to add the opencv libs to your project but you do need to link to the libraries and set the library search path. I was able to compile and run your program with these settings:

**Search paths:**
[image: Search paths]

**Link to libraries:**
[image: Linked libraries]

Comment: Yes!Thank you! BTW, the latest opencv version is 2.4.2, why your version is 2.4.9?

Comment: I did `git clone git://code.opencv.org/opencv.git` yesterday and that's what wound up in */usr/local/lib*.

Comment: Hi guys, I realise that this is very old now but I haven't really been able to find any documentation which is clear enough on how to set up openCV.framework to compile with iOS.  I've added the link to the binary OpenCV.framework and added the header and library search paths. I've been looking around and I haven't been able to fix this for a couple of days. I don't know what I've missed. Can anyone help me?

Comment: @AlecGamble: Just follow the above steps in adding the search paths and also adding the opencv libraries to the project and it should work fine. I just did it in a project.

Comment: @ssteve You have saved my day :)