# Library not found OpenCV

Tags: xcode, opencv

I'm on mac 10.7.5, using xcode 4.6.2 and working with the OpenCV 2.4.3 library. I went through the process of making the build directory with the cmake files in terminal and did the download.

I added the `.dylib` files in Xcode and changed the header path, changed C++ Library to libstdc++, but when I compiled I got this error :

```
ld: library not found for -lopencv_calib3d.2.4.3
clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1
```

I have `libopencv_calib3d.2.4.3.dylib` added in the project so I have no idea what else it needs.Any ideas?

Comment: Do you have anything like a "library path" in the architecture you are developing?
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9412296/ld-library-path-the-shared-lib-path-in-linux Does your compiler accept a flag like -L for gcc/g++? http://linux.die.net/man/1/g++

Comment: Thanks for the links. I have my Architectures as "Native Architecture of Build Machine" and my compiler to Default. If I add -L in other c++ flags I get the same error. -L isn't an option under my C++ library but could I add it and change the default compiler? Sorry I'm new to most of this.

Comment: I do not if it is clear, but you have to use `-L directory_where_your_library_is`

Answer (score 2):

If your "make back-end" is Cmake you should stick to using it. Local config changes in Xcode can "secretly" be overwritten when the cmake is rerun (which for example happens after you make changes to it) creating weird build errors and forcing you to remember all the manual changes you made.

Your problem seems to be that the generated project doesn't seem to know where to look for opencv.

Assuming you installed opencv using macports you should add a line saying

```
link_directories(/opt/local/lib)
```

to your CMakeLists.txt. (if you installed it using brew, or compiled it manually just replace `/opt/local/lib` for `/usr/local/lib` or the path to your compiled libraries)

Also make sure to link against `opencv_calib3d` instead of `opencv_calib3d.2.4.3` (unless you have a very particular reason for bypassing this, but that usually means that something else is weird in the setup :) )

Final pointer that you might already know of: As you are already using Cmake you should add the libraries to link against using TARGET_LINK_LIBRARIES(...) in Cmake rather than manually adding them in Xcode (referring to my previous argument).

Comment: I don't think OP is using cmake to build his own program. He only used cmake to build OpenCV

Comment: where can I add the link_directories?  Also when I add the files it says calib3d then after it's added it says calib3d.2.4.3

Comment: @AndreaF Sorry I misunderstood your setup. As I get it now you are not using make for your actual project so most my points don't apply. Instead take a look at this solution: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11726837/why-cant-i-compile-this-command-line-opencv-mac-application?rq=1

Comment: Thanks! That solution hasn't worked so maybe I should just start again. Any very clear tutorials you could recommend?